# Writing a bash or some other script to restart another script

Tags: java, linux, bash, minecraft

I am running a minecraft server for my son, i'm new at minecraft servers, anyway it seems it keeps dying as it cant keep up? ok so its a VM and i will be assigning more resources to it at some point but my question is as follows

I initiate the server to load up via a script 
bukkit.sh is the script an inside it has

```
#!/bin/bash
java -Xmx1024M -jar /minecraftserver/bukkitserver/craftbukkit-1.7.1.jar -o true
```

now at somepoint during the day or night it will die as it cant keep up, is there a way i can have some other script run alongside it and see that the process has died and to run that script again to start the server.

when i run top i can see that java is at the top using all the resources so im 100% thats the minecraft java. Does the PID stay the same each time it loads up?

Would be great if someone could let a hand on this ...

Comment: Have you messed with cron jobs before? I have a feeling this is what you need. You could schedule a script to check on the process to run every x minutes.

Comment: Do you know why it is crashing ? Not enough memory, computer is turned off,....

Comment: its a resource thing in VM, i knoiw the fix but cant afford the extra ram i need to put in it yet, so this is a temp fix to restart the script when it dies

Answer (score 1):

I assume the java process remains in the foreground once it's launched? Is there any reason you can't just do:

```
while :
do
  java -Xmx1024M -jar /minecraftserver/bukkitserver/craftbukkit-1.7.1.jar -o true
done
```

Then any time the java exits, the script will simply restart it.

Comment: yes the process loads an interactive console and stays in the foreground.

how do i implement this, just add it to the existing bukkit.sh script below the bin/bash

Comment: Yes, I would think so. Basically just find where the java invocation is currently and wrap it with the while loop.

Comment: didnt work came up with while: command not found and a syntax error

Comment: There's a space between the while and the colon.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
You could create a script, lets call it craftbukkit.sh

Make sure it is execute by using: `chmod +x craftbukkit.sh`

Then inside the script you would write:

```
#!/bin/sh

ps auxw | grep craftbukkit-1.7.1.jar| grep -v grep > /dev/null

if [ $? != 0 ]
then
        /path/to/your/bukkit.sh
fi
```

Change `/path/to/your/bukkit.sh` to wherever that minecraft startup script is.

Then you need to add this script to your crontab, this is accomplished by entering the crontab editor: `crontab -e`

If you want the script to run every 5 minutes, add a line that looks like this:

```
*/5 * * * * /path/to/craftbukkit.sh
```

Note that you must change the /path/to to point to where you have created the craftbukkit.sh script.

Comment: so when i run bukkit.sh which loads my jar file. in TOP it just runs as java.

So what commands can i try to get this working?

@marc , how would i init your script, would this just be that addition to the bukkit.sh script.

In terms of cron jobs, ive googled for this an im not quite sure how to get it working with pgrep?

Comment: It shows as java only it top because it is showing the process name, not the full command line. hit 'c' while in top it should toggle between the two options.

Comment: i get the following error

CraftBukkit.sh: 5: [: 1: unexpected operator

Comment: what if you change #!/bin/sh to #!/bin/bash  do you still receive that error?